# Cannot open output file in qt

Tags: qt

I'm working with Qt Creator 2.4.1 and I faced with one really annoying problem.

When I debug my project, I get following the error very often:

```
:-1: error: cannot open output file debug\qtrbdclient.exe: Permission denied
:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The only way to solve it is to close Qt Creator and run it again. I really can't understand why it happens again and again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the program is still running. Make sure any running instances are closed. You can use Task Manager or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to catch any open handles to your application.

Comment: There are no instances running.

Comment: Its most likely the System process (PID: 4) have a look here, as this seems to be a common issue with Vista/Windows 7 http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5397

Answer (score 0):

Check if Application Experience is running, it must be.
This causes this error on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when I tried to compile the release version. The problem was the resources file, that included new graphics. After removing the graphics again, Qt could open the output file again. I changed the graphics and it worked again...

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this problem when I was working on a Hello World QML exercise. Essentially I did not put my UI elements inside Window tag. When I ran the application, it will not open an application window; therefore, there is no way to close them or know that it's running.

Check under Application Output located at Window > Output Panes > Application Output (usually at the bottom). The stop button should be red and active. Click on that before running again.

[image]

Wrong Code:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 200
    ...
}
```

Right Code:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 360
    height: 200
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ...
    }
}
```